# How to change Magento main page

Tags: magento

I downloaded this Magento theme for mobile devices:

[enter link description here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blue-depth-mobile-theme-free-4986.html)http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blue-depth-mobile-theme-free-4986.html

It doesn’t use the CMS home page configured under `Admin > System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page`. Instead, it shows a list of categories.

When I view my page on a desktop computer, it uses the default theme and I see the CMS home page that I designed.  When I view it on a mobile device then I see the categories.

How do I change it so it shows a customized page?